# Can this function be considered tail recursive?

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

Here is my function :

```
    //Data Structures :
    abstract class HuffmanTree
  case class Node(left: HuffmanTree, right: HuffmanTree, chars: List[Char], weight: Int) extends HuffmanTree
  case class Leaf(char: Char, weight: Int) extends HuffmanTree


  def find_char(tree: HuffmanTree, x: Char, accu: List[Int]): (Boolean, List[Int]) = {
    tree match {
      case Leaf(c, _) => ((x == c),accu)
      case Node(left, right, ll, _) =>
      (find_char(left,  x,  accu ::: List(0))._1 || find_char(right, x,  accu :::List(1))._1, accu);
    }
  }
```

The function takes a huffman tree, a character and accumulator. The purpose of the function is to search the character in the huffman tree and to encode it. So I traverse the tree, when I go to the left, I add 0 to the accumulator and when I go to the right, I add 1 to the accumulator.

I would like to know if this function is tail recursive?

I also have another problem. When I reach a `Leaf`, the returned accumulator is always empty. Can someone explain me why I have this problem?

Comment: I answered to the first part. Your code contains syntax errors at the moment. It's consequently hard to tell what's wrong in it.

Comment: Just correct the syntax error. For the second part, the return accumulutator is empty.

Comment: There is still a parenthesis mismatch on the last line. If I understand it well, your issue comes from it. Can you copy/paste your actual code?

Comment: I updated the code. I added the data structure that I am using

Answer (score 11, accepted):

General hint: the `@tailrec` annotation can be used to check if a method is tail recursive.

Basically in you case, it is not tail recursive: in the `Node`case, there is an `||` operator between the two recursive calls.

Considering the empty list of `Int`. It's straightforward: you return the original value of `accu` in any case. If you called `find_char` with an empty list as a second parameter, you can't obtain something else than the empty list.

Comment: Even if I update the accumulator value in the recursive call??

Comment: List are immutable. There is no side effect. You don't "update" the accumulator. You create a **new** one, using the original one and a List of one element.

Comment: By update, I mean adding a new element to the list, I totally understand that. But I make the recursive call by adding a new element in the accumulator. So when I reach, the accumulator must have the all the 0's and 1's while traversing the tree. Isn't it?

Comment: yes, but in a line when you call (find_char || find_char, accu) you return an empty accumulator as a second tuple element, not the one returned from a recursive call

Comment: `@tailrec` can't catch everything. I (stupidly) wrote a method a little while back that I thought was tail-recursive, and it even passed the compiler with the `@tailrec` annotation, but it wasn't making any true recursive calls because I was calling the method on a different instance of the class. E.g. `next.find(value)` instead of `find(next, value)`. I had to re-structure the method to use an explicit parameter to the current node instead of just using `this` to actually get tail calls.

Comment: Yes, `@tailrec` ensure that you can perform a tail recursion optimisation... If you don't have any recursive call (calling the wrong method for example), the optimisation is easy to perform.